# query not working properly using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

I really don't undestand what is happening in here, 
This the form that im using which ask for a studentcode = lz.

```
  <form action="classgrades.php?id=<?php echo $courseid ?>" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="studentCode" value="" placeholder="Student Code.." />
       <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button> 
  </form>
```

and this query to select the data from the table

```
$studentcode = $_POST['studentCode']; 
 $query = "SELECT fname FROM students WHERE studentcode = $studentcode";
```

I don't undestand whay im getting this error

```
ErrorSQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'lz' in 'where clause'
```

and if I try with a student code that is a number work, but not for letters

Comment: Seems Like `studentcode` is of VARCHAR type SO use: 
`$query = "SELECT fname FROM students WHERE studentcode = '$studentcode'";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to give characters as values, then you have to enclose it in quotes. Try with

```
$query = "SELECT fname FROM students WHERE studentcode = '$studentcode'";
```